# Python xml help? Finish my program?

Tags: python, xml

I need help finishing a python program that will write values to an xml. Having learned basic python concepts in the past few months, I am in way over my head and am unsure how to proceed. I have spent the last several hours researching but have come up blank. My code is:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

#Initialize xml file

speed = 0
t = 0
acc = 0
dt = 5/60
print ('This program writes a set of values to an xml file.')
#output header to file
#output to file: t, acc, speed

while (speed < 100):
   acc = acc + 5
   speed = speed + acc*dt
   t = t + dt
   #Output to file: t, acc, speed
acc = 0
while (t <= 5):
   t = t + 1
   #Output to file: t, acc, speed
while (speed > 0):
   acc = acc - 5
   speed = speed + acc*dt
   t = t + dt
   #Output to file: t, acc, speed

#Close output file
print ('Program done!')
```

The lines with the (#) need completion.

I have tried several different ways I have found online, but they do not work and I do not understand why.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you like the XML file to be structured?

Comment: The file needs to be able to later be used to create graphs on excel. Besides that, I am open to any structuring as there are no constraints given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a root element using `ET.Element()`, adding the children you want to it. Then, you give that as the root to an `ET.ElementTree`, and call `.write()` on that, setting `xml_declaration` to `True`.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET


def record_time(root, time, speed, acc):
    attribs = {"t": str(time), "speed": str(speed), "acc": str(acc)}
    ET.SubElement(root, "record", attribs)

root = ET.Element("data")

speed = 0
t = 0
acc = 0
dt = 5/60
print ('This program writes a set of values to an xml file.')

#output to file: t, acc, speed
record_time(root, t, speed, acc)

while (speed < 100):
   acc = acc + 5
   speed = speed + acc*dt

   t = t + dt
   record_time(root, t, speed, acc)
acc = 0
while (t <= 5):
   t = t + 1
   record_time(root, t, speed, acc)
while (speed > 0):
   acc = acc - 5
   speed = speed + acc*dt
   t = t + dt
   record_time(root, t, speed, acc)

#The following lines automatically create, write and close your xml for you, with the appropriate XML header.
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("YOUR_FILENAME_HERE.xml", xml_declaration=True)

print ('Program done!')
```